# Drain hose of washing machine too low?

Tags: plumbing, washing-machine, drainage, hose, overflow

I just bought a front load washing machine and installed it. The plumbers in our bldg. installed the incoming water hose and the drain hose to the wall. Problem is that when the washing machine drains, the water overflows or comes out of the hole where the drain hose is inserted. Do I really need a high drainage pipe to connect my drain hose into?

This is the instruction I got from the internet for my washer's brand.

[image]

And here is the wall that has the drain hole in my kitchen and also my hose inserted into it.
You can see how low the hole in the wall is and the bending of my hose.

[image]
[image]

I tried inserting the hose as much as i could into the hole but still overflows or water comes back out and floods my kitchen.

Comment: Just as a quick comment to be sure... Is it possible that the drain line has something blocking it up?

Comment: Well our plumber said they already fixed it and should be okay. But I asked them to check again. But does it matter if my drain hole is too low or maybe the position of my hose is causing too much water to be drained and so the overflow?

Comment: No, I would figure not. As long as the hose is inserted far enough into the pipe for any immediate pressure, and there is nothing blocking it from draining, then it should be fine. Are you able to try and test pouring a bucket with a spout or such of water down the drain to see if it would also come back up?

Comment: +1 for "As long as the hose is inserted far enough into the pipe". Make sure the end of the hose is not hitting the side of the pipe. I assume it should be parallel with it... probably inserted at least a 6-12".

Comment: Okay. Will try myself to pour in a bucket. Will also see how much far I can put in the hose in the hole without forcefully damaging it.

Comment: Okay. I just tried pouring in 500ml of water 3 consecutive times and didn't overflow. Another cause I guess is that I am testing the draining of water without clothes on the washer. Maybe it outputs too much water and has too much outer pressure causing to blow back the water?

Comment: I tried also inserting the hose but it stops at a certain level.

Comment: Try pouring more more like 20,000ml very quickly (although this might be nearly impossible to pour quickly with the pipe in the wall).   Washing machines usually drain the bulk of the water at a VERY high volume per minute compared to a sink or a tub.  Pipe is either blocked, not vented, or undersized or combination of all three.

Comment: Maybe getting a 2nd opinion from a good local plumber would help, especially if the drain needs to be changed / worked on (a free quote would be great), it would go a long way to get your "*building plumber*" to do the job right / fix it (if you don't have to pay them extra). I'm a little surprised to see an open drain pipe flush with a wall like that, it looks like someone took a saw to an old good drain pipe. And +1 to Damon's suggestion, 500ml is nothing to a washing machine, an upright washer can hold 27 to 40 **gallons** (100 to 150 L) of water

Comment: I'm not sure that just pouring water will sufficiently simulate a washing machine draining. Remember, a washer has an impeller which pumps the water giving added pressure and flow. This is part of why partial blockage might not be noticed by anything other than the washer.

Comment: Well, I have just decided that I put the hose into a hole on the floor in our kitchen. Perhaps add an extension to the drain hose too.

I am very thankful for all the comments and responses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to assume that there's not a trap inside the wall, but if I'm wrong please correct me.

You're going to want to build a **standpipe**.  Start by installing a P-trap into that pipe in the wall.  It's hard to tell from the picture what type of pipe it is, but you'll want to use something compatible to make the connection between pipe and trap.

From the other end of the P-trap, you'll want a 2" diameter pipe going straight up 18"-42" long.

You'll then put the washer drain into the top of the standpipe, as described in the manufacturer's installation instructions.

When you're done, it should look something like this.

[image]

Comment: I agree; this is really the best solution.

Answer (score 5):

When discharging directly into a waste system without a standpipe, the connections must be "tight", as with a hose clamp to an appropriately sized tube connector, as shown in the manufacturer's instructions.

The standpipe method is better (in my opinion) when connecting to existing waste systems with unknown capacity, because the standpipe can be sized to accommodate the high volume discharge of the appliance water pump. The standpipe holds the water, allowing it to drain down into the system of dubious capacity. When building a standpipe you do not *have* to use the pre-made 2" units. I prefer to create one with larger diameter plastic pipe components, for more capacity.

Both methods require a trap.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the room, you could put in a slop sink.  Then the water can drain more slowly, no matter how fast the washing machine exhausts.